# don´t recognize variable of php

Tags: php, action

I have the following code in two files separately

file one.php

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM ACTION="two.php" METHOD="POST">
   Age: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="age">
   <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="OK">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

file dos.php

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?PHP
   print ("The age is: $age");
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

the age variable is not recognized, someone knows fix?

Comment: `$age=$_POST['age'];` there. Next time, Google it. Use this too `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: you must be developing for a stone-age version of PHP. `register_globals` was deprecated a LONG time ago and was disabled by default even longer ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to access the value of age from a page( dos.php) but you posting it to (two.php) and your missing $_POST['age'].

one.php

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM ACTION="two.php" METHOD="POST">
Age: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="age">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="OK">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

two.php

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?PHP
$age = $_POST['age'];
print ("The age is: $age");
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not recognized because you don't create it. Variables don't magically appear in PHP<sup>1</sup>. You need to get that value from the [`$_POST` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php):

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?PHP
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   print ("The age is: $age");
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

<sup>1</sup> Anymore. They used to when [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) existed. But that has been obsolete since long before you started coding.

Comment: *"But that has been obsolete since long before you started coding."* - That may even apply to me also lol - But I took the [**initiative**](http://www.google.com) when I didn't know why my forms weren't working.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If only everyone knew about Google. I wonder what we can do to spread the word about that new website and it's magical abilities?

Comment: I know eh? I remember when Google first magically appeared and thought, "hey, I should compare this wonderful piece of sliced bread to what I see before me" ;) I was eating a sandwich at the time. Now it's all up to Harry, Mr. Potter to some to carry on the tradition.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: New-fangled nonsense! [Back in the day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) ... ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog Just a wee bit before my time, but I did hear of it when I got into 'pewters. BBS's were what the Kool Kids were using at the time ;)